# Finiteness in compact space classification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $X$ be a metric space satisfying that every sequence in $X$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $X$.

> Lemma: Any metric space satisfying the above condition has a countable dense subset.

I draw the proof from [Stromberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1470425440). He begins the proof by claiming that there exists a finite set $A_\epsilon \subseteq X$ satisfying

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\rho(a,b)\geq\epsilon\; {\rm whenever}\; a\neq b\; {\rm in }\; A_\epsilon,\\
&B_\epsilon(x) \cap A_\epsilon \neq \emptyset\; {\rm for\; each}\; x\in X.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The proof goes by contradicting that no such $A_\epsilon$ exists. Everything is understandable, since if no such $A_\epsilon$ exists, one can construct a sequence that does not have a convergent subsequence. The only question that I have is that why the requierement that $A_\epsilon$ is finite is needed. I don't see in the proof that if the set is infinite, how the contradiction of no convergent subsequence may arise.

The proof that the above set must exists goes as follows

> Assume that the above conditions are false. Let $x_1\in X$. When $x_1,\dots,x_n \in X$ have been chosen so that $\rho(x_i,x_j)\geq \epsilon$ if $i\neq j$, we observe that the set $\lbrace x_1,\dots, x_n\rbrace$ satisfies the first condition, so it cannot satisfy the second. Thus, there exists $x_{n+1}\in X$ such that $$B_\epsilon (x_{n+1})\cap\lbrace x_1,\dots,x_n\rbrace = \emptyset;$$ whence $\rho(x_{n+1},x_i)\geq \epsilon$ for $1\geq i \geq n$. In this way we inductively choose a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq X$ such that $\rho(x_i,x_j)\geq \epsilon$ whenever $i\neq j$ in $\mathbb{N}$. (...)

Comment: We are looking for a *countable* dense set: we will take the union of the countably many finite sets $A_{1/n}$, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that's the result of the contradiction. What I am missing is, if you assume that the two conditions are false, why at the end $A_\epsilon$ must be finite? In other words, why I cannot have $A_\epsilon$ with the above conditions such that the set is infinite?

Comment: How is that nonconverging sequence defined? I suspect the finiteness of $A_\epsilon$ is implicitly used there.

Comment: Ah, is it the conclusion that the sequence $(x_n)$ is infinite?

Comment: Yes. Failure of the two conditions for *all finite sets* guarantees that we can construct the whole sequence. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of that sequence should go as follow:

By contradiction, we assume that there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that *no finite set* $A$ satisfies the two conditions together, i.e. whenever $A$ is a finite set with the first property ($d(a,b)\ge\varepsilon\ \forall a,b\in A$) then it fails the second property, so there is an $x\in X$ whose $\varepsilon$-neighborhood is disjoint from $A$.

First choose an arbitrary element $a_1\in X$.
Then we repeatedly apply the above to add the $x$ found above *for the finite set* $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ as the next element: $a_{n+1}:=x$.
The main observation is that $A$ satisfies the first property, by construction.

And that's it. Since this construction was applied only for finite sets, we can draw the given conclusion.